# How to integrate Apple pay into watch app?

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, watchkit, apple-watch, payment-processing

I want to access the Watchkit API for Apple pay and Healthkit data, to accomplish payment from my watch app.

Is this possible, or is there any apple document where the API access limitation is described?

Answer (score 1):

WatchKit does not yet support the Apple Pay API, but you could use handoff to open a specific ViewController on the iPhone where the user can use Apple Pay.

https://developer.apple.com/handoff/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/96741/watchkit-tutorial-with-swift-tables-glances-and-handoff

Update:
WatchKit *does* now support Apple Pay. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacepaymentbutton?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

You can access HealthKit data by opening your iPhone app in the background using `openParentApplication:reply:` and accessing it from there.

There's no Apple Pay API for WatchKit at this time. The documentation that shows this fact is simply that no such API is currently in the documentation.